# How to run g++ output files

Tags: 14.04, g++

I compiled my c++ program with g++ and I can only run the output with ./ProgramName. Is there any way I can just double click the file to run it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to change file settings through the file properties.

[image]

Fill the "Allow executing file as program", then double click on binary file to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to, since it produces an executable file.

If the program just outputs some stuff to `stdout`, then you have to run it in a shell. If there is some window that comes up, then you can run it through a file manager or the shell.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are try to a CLI program (no GUI). You have to wrap it within a shell or create a .desktop file.

Shell wrap example:

```
#!/usr/sh
/path-to/ProgramName

#to wait till press Enter
read
```

.desktop file example:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Program Name
Exec=/path-to/ProgramName
Terminal=true
```